# c# how to trigger click only at certain position

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# `UserControl`. Within the it I have overriden the `OnPaint` method. Then I draw a circle inside it.

```
Bitmap GraphicsImage = new Bitmap(24, 24, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics.FromImage(GraphicsImage).Clear(btnColor);

Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(btnColor);
Pen myPen = new Pen(btnColor);
// Draw the button in the form of a circle
graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, 40, 40);
graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40));
```

Here is the Image

[image]

What I want is to trigger the mouse click event only when the mouse is inside the circle, because the usercontrol is bigger.

Comment: Just a FYI, `Pen` and `SolidBrush` are both disposable and should be disposed when done with (just put them in `using` statements).

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger **all click events** on the user control, and check if the mouse position is inside the circle

```
private void yourcontrol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = yourcontrol.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition);
    //check if point is in the circle with 
    if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pt.X - xCenterOfCircle, 2) + Math.Pow(pt.Y - yCenterOfCOircle, 2)) < radius)
    {
      //do something   
    }
}
```

`xCenterOfCircle` has to be the x position of the center of your circle and `yCenterOfCircle` the y position. I assume in your example it is the center of your control and the radius would be half the size of your control.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that by overriding `OnMouseDown`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.MouseClick"/> event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs"/> that contains the event data. </param>
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var centerX = Left + Width/2.0;
    var centerY = Top + Height/2.0;
    var dist = (e.X - centerX)*(e.X - centerX) + (e.Y - centerY)*(e.Y - centerY);
    if(dist <= (radius*radius))
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

So, if the mouse is within a given radius of the center of the control (using Pythagoras's theorem, pass on the click event.  Otherwise, ignore it, as the control hasn't *actually* been clicked.

You can then add event handlers to `control.Click` as normal.

Edit: to duplicate the example code exactly, change:

```
var centerX = 20; //(40-0) / 2
var centerY = 20;
```